# F lack of fit test in R, the reduced model doesn’t use factors

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, anova

I have some notes which show how to conduct a lack of fit test in R.  They use the code

```
> Reduced <- lm(y ~ x, data=corrosion) 
> summary(Reduced)

> Full <- lm(y~factor(x))
> summary(Full)
```

I’m having some trouble understanding what a “reduced model” and “full model” is in this context.  I understood the ideas when it came to regression but how those ideas transfer to the lack of fit test, I don’t seem to quite get.

With this R code it seems like the distinction is that in the reduced model the independent variable is numeric when in the full model it’s a factor variable (which I think of as like a categorical variable).  In what sense does this amount to the reduced/full distinction?

Comment: I don't understand either.   If you had x1 and x2, then the full model would be y ~ x1 + x2 and reduced would be y ~ x1 or y ~ x2.   I think the choice of whether to use x as is or as.factor depends entirely on the data in x.   The only thing is, you will get a lot more parameters estimates in the so-called Full model, but I don't really see what that has to do with anything.

Comment: @Paul Hewson well at least I’m not crazy for thinking this isn’t obvious!  But I believe I’ve seen other posts on CrossValidated where they apply this strategy too.  So I suspect that somehow it’s right.  But in general I don’t even see how regression easily adapts to the lack-of-fit test.  The model in H_0 is a linear one but not for the y values, rather for the means of the y-value sets.  I think.

Comment: @Paul You might be using a different concept of "reduced" and "full."  To understand the concept in *this* setting, inspect the model matrices for the two formulas given in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The terminology I use (and prefer) is to call the model `~factor(x)` a *saturated model*. That means the predicted value of $Y$ at each "observation level" (unique combination of covariates) is the empirical mean of $Y$ at that observation level. The actual coding of "x" in the "Reduced" model (which again I would prefer to call the "candidate" model) is irrelevant, except that if it is already saturated, there is no use to doing the comparison.

To clarify further, suppose $X$ is age, and say you're wondering about the adequacy of coding age in 10 year increments, then in the candidate model, you would create the factor `y ~ cut(age, 0:10*10)` but the saturated model needs `y ~ factor(age)` to obtain a unique prediction for ages 40, 41, 42, ... only this way can you say if the 10 year increment has suitable predictive accuracy.

Comment: Changing names is fine but I’m missing how regression can analyze the problem. I see how regressing on the factor variable gives H_0, the saturated model.  But why would the candidate model be the one with numeric xs? Usually this is just the one with parameters =/= 0. Since we then call `anova(Reduced, Full)` and conduct the typical F-test it seems like there has to be some kind of literal sense in which the full/candidate model is the one with all the parameters.  But in H_a there aren’t a bunch of parameters.